# What is this cardioid/fish-like graphic that appears in FFXVI when looking at the sun?

Tags: raytracing, lighting

In Final Fantasy 16, a recent video game, when looking towards the setting sun, one sees several circles, which seem like the lens flare that one commonly sees in games. But the most prominent (circle) is this cardioid/fish-like curve that loops in on itself. I've never seen this before. FFXVI has insane polish, so I don't think this is some random mistake by the devs. Does this phenomenon have any basis in reality? Is it just some weird stylistic choice? Or is it just a graphical mistake?

Here's an image from ffxvi, demonstrating what I'm talking about.

https://files.catbox.moe/mgagg4.png

Comment: All lens flare images you can find show convex shapes (most often circles, but also the shape of the iris). On your picture, there are two flares with a caustic and one circle slightly off-axis. The leftmost is not circular. The "nodal point" of the "cardioid" seems to lie on the circumference, but that might just be a coincidence.